# run macros assigned to many excel sheets of a workbook, with one click

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, microsoft-outlook, vba

I have one workbook with 8 worksheets.

I have a macro assigned to each worksheet.

I want to run all 8 macros from one worksheet in one click(by clicking one button, to run all 8 macros).

How can this be performed?

Answer (score 0):

Create a ninth wrapper macro that calls each of the 8 macros in turn, and assign that wrapper macro to the control button.